# How to limit characters and stop calculation in Calculator Screen

Tags: ios, integer, uilabel

[image]

I'm using some calculator methods for my Login Screen.

Such as:

```
- (IBAction)numberPressed:(id)sender
{
currentNumber = currentNumber *10 + (float)[sender tag];
calculatorScreen.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%2.f", currentNumber];
}
```

and

```
- (IBAction)C:(id)sender
{
[self setCurrentNumber:0];
calculatorScreen.text = @"Enter Password";
}
```

**I am stuck with two things:**

1. I need to limit the number of characters in the *calculatorScreen.text* to 7 characters.
2. I need to stop the number from multiplying after **8** entries.

   - I'm not sure what the reasoning is exactly, but after 8 button-presses the numbers start to multiply (change from original button number)

Have been looking around and trying different things and can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you working with a `UITextField` or what?

Comment: No, the buttons send float integers to the UILabel

Comment: Then keep track of how many buttons have been tapped using an instance variable. Disable the keyboard after the limit is reached.

Answer (score 0):

To limit characters to 7:

```
- (IBAction)numberPressed:(id)sender
{
currentNumber = currentNumber *10 + (float)[sender tag];

if ([calculatorScreen.text length] == 7)

{        
    return;
}

else {

calculatorScreen.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%2.f", currentNumber];

self.calculatorString = calculatorScreen.text;

}
}
```

Still not sure on how to fix the 'multiply' issue. If a user has a password over 8 characters, it's going to be a problem. But for now, I will set it to 7 characters to prevent it.